# adding required attribute to materializedcss select with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, drop-down-menu, materialize

I'm trying to add the `required` attribute to a materializedcss select input using jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
  $("#my_button").click(function() {
    $("#my_select").prop('required', true);
    $("#email").prop('required', false);
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="input-field col s12 required">
        <select id="my_select">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
        <label>Materialize Select</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
      </div>
      <a id='my_button' class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>
      <button class="btn  waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Looking at the DOM the attribute is added OK but for some reason the validation then doesn't seem to go through properly. When I add the 'required' attribute directly the validation works fine.

There's some code to make the validation look good ([from here](http://jsfiddle.net/b8frk03m/6/)) but it's the same result without it. I'm relatively new to this so would appreciate any clues.
Thanks

Comment: A fiddle is helpful, but please make sure all relevant code is *in the question*. This is so that you can still get an answer even if jsFiddle goes down

Comment: Thanks for the tip, still new at this!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `$("#email").prop('required', false);` that's why it is not adding required to that `input` element with `email` as an id.

#### Change this line:

`$("#email").prop('required', false);`

#### To

`$("#email").prop('required', true);`

and `required` will be added on click of `my_button`.

Comment: Thanks, adding and removing to the email input is fine, the question is about the select input. Removing the attribute is fine, but not adding.